# Mostrar valores do banco de dados em uma JList na tela

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

Olá, estou criando uma aplicação que necessita mostrar alguns elementos registrados em uma lista, que mostrarei através do DefaultListModel. Infelizmente dentro da aplicação ele reconhece os elementos que foram inseridos mas não como deveria, já que ele não mostra o nome do elemento mas sim o caminho da entidade, queria saber como faço pro DeufaltListModel reconhecer meu objeto e os elementos dentro dele como tipo String, não como código aleatório. Já vi um post semelhante mas não funcionou pra mim lá diz pra sobrescrever o toString() mas ainda assim não funciona.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Codigo da classe que cria o componete de tela e dentro dele metodos para buscar os valores do Banco:

```
 public class CargosConsultar  extends JPanel{
    Cargos cargoAtual;
    JLabel labelTitulo, labelCargo;
    JTextField campoCargo;
    JButton botaoPesquisar, botaoEditar, botaoExcluir;
    DefaultListModel <Cargos> listasCargosModelo = new DefaultListModel();
    JList <Cargos> listaCargos = new JList();
    
public CargosConsultar(){
criarComponentes();
criarEventos();
} 
private void criarComponentes() {
   setLayout (null);
   labelTitulo = new JLabel("Consulta de cargos", JLabel.CENTER);
   labelTitulo.setFont(new Font(labelTitulo.getFont().getName(), Font.PLAIN, 20));
   labelCargo = new JLabel ("Nome do cargo", JLabel.LEFT);
   campoCargo = new JTextField();
   botaoPesquisar = new JButton("Pesquisar Cargo");
   botaoEditar = new JButton ("Editar Cargo");
   botaoEditar.setEnabled(false);
   botaoExcluir = new JButton ("Excluir Cargo");
   botaoExcluir.setEnabled(false);
   listasCargosModelo = new DefaultListModel();
   listaCargos = new JList();
   listaCargos.setModel(listasCargosModelo);
   listaCargos.setSelectionMode(javax.swing.ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
   
   labelTitulo.setBounds(20, 20, 660, 40);
   labelCargo.setBounds(150, 120, 400, 20);
   campoCargo.setBounds(20, 140, 400, 40);
   botaoPesquisar.setBounds(560, 140, 130, 40);
   listaCargos.setBounds(150, 200, 400, 240);
   botaoEditar.setBounds(560, 360, 130, 40);
   botaoExcluir.setBounds(560, 400, 130, 40);
   
   add(labelTitulo);
   add(labelCargo);
   add(campoCargo);
   add(botaoPesquisar);
   add(listaCargos);
   add(botaoEditar);
   add(botaoExcluir);
  
   
   setVisible(true);
    }
   private void criarEventos(){
   botaoPesquisar.addActionListener(e ->{
       
   sqlConsultaCargos(campoCargo.getText());
   
   });
   
   }
    private void sqlConsultaCargos(String nome){
    Statement instrucaoSQL;
    ResultSet rs;

    try {
        //conectando no banco de dados
       Connection con = ConnectionFactory.getConnection();
        //criando a instrução SQL
       instrucaoSQL = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
       rs = instrucaoSQL.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM cargo WHERE nome like '%"+nome+"%'");

    listasCargosModelo.clear();
    while(rs.next()){
    Cargos cargo = new Cargos();
    cargo.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
    cargo.setNome(rs.getString("nome"));
    listasCargosModelo.addElement(cargo);
    System.out.println("nome"+ cargo.getNome());
    con.close();
    }
    }catch(SQLException ex){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Ocorreu um erro ao consultar os cargos"+ ex);
    
    }
       
    }
    
}
```

Classe que possui a entidade dos Cargos:

```
public class Cargos {
    private int id;
    private String nome;
@Override
   public String toString(){
  return getNome();
   }
   
    
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
     
    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolvido, havia instanciado o Jlist e o DefaultModel duas vezes, deixei apenas a instancia no inicio da classe e rodou.